# Postgres dates and extracting week numbers - inconsistent results

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, week-number

I've been doing some statistics analysis of data in a Postgres (v10.6) database grouped by ISO week and have stumbled upon an apparent inconsistency in how week numbers are returned, for instance:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week',TIMESTAMP '2019-02-14'),'WW');
```

returns **06**

whereas:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-02-14');
```

returns **7**

Why is there a discrepancy / which one of these is correct ? I suspect the latter, as the equivalent operation in PHP returns **07** too:

```
$dte = new DateTime('2019-02-14');
echo $dte->format('W');
```

I'm mostly concerned that there is some good reason for this difference that I'm missing ...

Answer (score 3):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) `'WW'` returns

> week number of year (1-53) (**the first week starts on the first day of the year**)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

`extract(week ...)` [always returns the ISO week](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). If you want `to_char()` to also return the ISO week, you need to use `'IW'` instead. If you also want to display the year with `to_char()` you should use `'IYYY'` instead of `'YYYY'` which is equivalent to `extract(isoyear ...)`